# ALTER CHANNEL fails with AMQ8242: SSLCIPH definition wrong

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

I try to alter channel definition as:

```
ALTER CHANNEL(CNL_TEST) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(TRIPLE_DES_SHA_US) SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
AMQ8242: SSLCIPH definition wrong.
```

using same cipher names as are listed in WebSphere MQ Explorer: Channels -> Properties -> SSL: SSL Cipher Spec but it fails with AMQ8242.

Not sure why but this Cipher Spec is not specified in ALTER CHANNEL command description:
http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q085170_.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because SSLv3 CipherSpecs, which includes TRIPLE_DES_SHA_US, were deprecated from MQ V8.0.0.2.  So you must be using this version of the product or later.  Take a look here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q123420_.htm

This is also why this CipherSpec is not listed on the supported CipherSpecs page here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014260_.htm

If you ***must*** use this CipherSpec then you can update the queue manager's qm.ini file as stated at the bottom of the first link to re-enable it:

```
SSL:
   AllowSSLV3=Y
   AllowWeakCipherSpec=ALL
```

Bounce the queue manager to pick up the changes.

However you really should be trying to use a TLSv1.2 Cipher.

Comment: Thanks for help! I already did it but for other manager and forgot the mq.ini files are unique for each Q manager... To TLSv1.2 there is a little problem to use it with Oracle JRE, but download the MQ server patch to support Oracle JRE cipher suites

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted.  And yes, the qm.ini files are specific to each queue manager.  If you're satisified with the answer, could you mark it as "accepted" please?